# Can't Display Image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add images in a columns using Advanced Custom Fields but the images doesn't display. But it displays the url of the images.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php if( have_rows('columns-1-services') ): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php while(have_rows('columns-1-services')):the_row(); {
            $image_1 = get_sub_field("images-1");
            $image_2 = get_sub_field("images-2");
            $image_3 = get_sub_field("images-3");
            $image_4 = get_sub_field("images-4");
        } ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 services"><?php echo "$image_1"; ?></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 services"><?php echo "$image_2"; ?></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 services"><?php echo "$image_3"; ?></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 services"><?php echo "$image_4"; ?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>  
    <?php
        else :
        // no rows found
        endif;?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As LucasNesk has said, the `get_sub_field("image")` function is returning a url rather than a full `img` tag.

Rather than using the url in a tag, I would recommend changing the field in settings to return the ID, and then using WordPress functions to output the image tag. That way you can easily use a thumbnail size and WP handles a responsive srcset for you.

From https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/#template-usage

```php
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

if( $image ) {

    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are rendering the image URL directly into the HTML page.

Try to put it in a Image tag at the src attribute, like:

```
<div class="col-md-3 services">
    <img src="<?php echo $image_1; ?>">
</div>
```

This will render your URL in the source attribute and load your image properly.

References of img tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img